# In R: Sum rows for new dataframe

Tags: r

How can I sum rows and raname for new dataframe in R?
I would sum and rename for create a new dataframe

Table1 > table2

[image: Table1>table2]

Comment: create new column for new names, `substr()` can help and then google how to do group by in R

Answer (score 0):

As said by @abhiieor in the comments, you could use `substr` for that. On you example:

```
t1$gr <- substr(t1$letts,1,1)
aggregate(euro ~ gr, t1, sum)
```

The result:

```
  gr euro
1  A  121
2  B  132
3  C   88
```

Note: it is better to include a reproducible example in your question, like this:

```
t1 <- data.frame(letts = sprintf('%s0%s', rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 3), 1:3)[-9],
                 euro = c(55, 43, 23, 50, 60, 22, 34, 54))
```

Answer (score -1):

for the rowSums you can use

```
yourRowSums <- rowSums(yourDataFrame)
```

not sure what you want to do more... maybe:

```
yourRowSums <- as.data.frame(yourRowSums)
```

Comment: Image Table1>Table2. Thanks :)